# What does {0} stands for in Console.WriteLine?

Tags: c#, console, console.writeline

Given the code :

```
// person.cs
using System;

// #if false

class Person
{
    private string myName = "N/A";
    private int myAge = 0;

    // Declare a Name property of type string:
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return myName;
        }
        set
        {
            myName = value;
        }
    }

    // Declare an Age property of type int:
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return myAge;
        }
        set
        {
            myAge = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name = " + Name + ", Age = " + Age;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Simple Properties");

        // Create a new Person object:
        Person person = new Person();

        // Print out the name and the age associated with the person:
        Console.WriteLine("Person details - {0}", person);

        // Set some values on the person object:
        person.Name = "Joe";
        person.Age = 99;
        Console.WriteLine("Person details - {0}", person);

        // Increment the Age property:
        person.Age += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Person details - {0}", person);
    }
}

// #endif
```

The output of the code is :

```
Simple Properties
Person details - Name = N/A, Age = 0
Person details - Name = Joe, Age = 99
Person details - Name = Joe, Age = 100
```

What does the `{0}` in `Console.WriteLine("Person details - {0}", person);` stands for ? 
How come it's replaced by `Name.....` ?

When I put `{1}` instead of `{0}` I get an exception ...

Comment: Look up the documentation for the method.  It explains it, in quite a lot of detail.

Comment: To add to what Servy said, the documentation can be found by googling "Console.WriteLine". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see, There's a code on your person object that returns a string, Console checks for If a type of string with name of ToString exists on your object class or not, If exists then It returns your string:

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return "Name = " + Name + ", Age = " + Age;
}
```

And {0} Is a formatted message, When you define It to {0} It means printing/formatting the zero Index object that you Inserted Into params arguments of your function. It's a zero based number that gets the index of object you want, Here's an example:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} Is great, {1} Do you think of It? {2} Think {0} Is great!", "C#", "What", "I");

// C# Is great, What do you think of It? I think C# Is great!
```

When you say {0} It gets C# or the [0] of your object[].

Answer (score 4):

It refers to the index number of the parameter.
For example, if you want to print multiple variables you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Person details - {0} {1}", person1, person2)
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Write`/`WriteLine` calls the first parameter is the format string. Format specifiers are enclosed in curly braces. Each specifier consists of a numeric reference to the parameter that needs to be "plugged into" the format string as the replacement of the said specifier, and optional formatting instructions for the corresponding data item.

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "You collected {0} items of the {1} items available.", // Format string
    itemsCollected,                                        // Will replace {0}
    itemsTotal                                             // Will replace {1}
);
```

This is similar to `printf` in C/C++, where `%...` specify the formatting for the corresponding item from the list of arguments. One major difference is that the `printf` family of functions requires that parameters and their format specifiers were listed in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the index of the given variable (first variable, second variable, etc.), whose contents you want to write. You have just one variable (`person`), that's why you can only set the first index (0).

In `Console.WriteLine("Person details - {0}", person);` the `{0}` means: write the contents of the first variable right where `{0}` is.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to learn about this stuff is the examples-part of this site:

[Console.WriteLine Method (String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/586y06yf.aspx)